# How to install clpqr library in SWI-Prolog

Tags: package-management, programming

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and going to write Prolog program with [clpqr](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpqr.html). I write this in first line:

```
:- use_module(library(clpr)).
```

I got this message:

```
source_sink `library(clpr)' does not exist
```

So, how to install that library? I've found some [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/swi-prolog/+bug/81561) about this, but maybe there's another way to install it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find the answer.

1. Download one from http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable/src/
2. Install the dependencies listed in http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/Debian.html
3. Finish by reading the instruction in README.linux